# How to display success message using autoform in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am using https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform for one of my meteor collections. I am using quickForm and type insert. Here is the relevant code:

```
<template name="postInsert">
   <legend>Add your story here</legend>
   {{> quickForm collection="Posts" id="insertPostForm" type="insert" buttonContent="Post!" resetOnSuccess=true}}
</template>
```

This form submits and creates the post successfully. But it doesn't display a success message. I know I can use the onSuccess hooks and write my own success message. But I was wondering if there is a standard way to display success message using an autoform configuration?

I looked through the documentation on github and searched a bit, but all solutions point to using the onSuccess hooks. Any pointers here are appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After extensive search it turns out, onSuccess hooks ARE the standard way to display a success message. Here is my implementation of the same for completeness and for anyone else who might stumble upon this question in the future.

> NEW Autoform 6.0.0

```
onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
    FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Success!');
    Router.go("/posts");
},
```

> OLD

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['postInsert', 'postUpdate'], {
  onSuccess: function(operation, result, template) {
    FlashMessages.sendSuccess('Success!');
    Router.go("/posts");
  }
});
```

The use of *AutoForm.addHooks* keeps the code DRY allowing reuse for update as well as insert operations.

Also I am using the excellent [flash-messages](https://github.com/camilosw/flash-messages) to display all my user messages. Highly recommended.

Comment: Where is this code located? I can't seem to get anything running client-side.  Also, is `postInsert ` your Template name? Thanks

Comment: Update: code runs client side, and Yes, the array passed to `addHooks` contains names of templates where the form is. :D  Turns out I was using the wrong template name (docs not clear)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but according to the [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks), it seems Autoform.addHooks now takes the formId.

So you would bind your autoform with id 'insertPostForm' using

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['insertPostForm'], {
     onSuccess: function (operation, result, template) {
              ...
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc on github, signatures changed for **onSuccess hook**

```
AutoForm.addHooks(['yourForm'],{
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
        Router.go('page',{_id: this.docId});
    }
});
```

Best is to check the up to date signatures: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks